# Why does `/` in try_files break `~ \.php$`

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to figure out why the prepending `/` is not allowing the `\.php$` locations directive from picking up the script.

Below is a sample .conf I'm using for nginx. We're running API code, versioned out in path: `//domian.com/v#.#/endpoint/uri`

Our document_root is one directory below the version number; `index.php` exists within the version directory: `path/to/sites/public/v1.0/index.php`

```
index index.php # <-- this is in here globally
location ~ ^/(?<version>v[\d\.]+) {
    try_files $uri $version/index.php?$args;
    # Why does this NOT work? The / stopping \.php$ from matching
    # try_files $uri /$version/index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {

    fastcgi_pass php56;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    [...]
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things, but can't seem to get this working. Once I remove the `/` it works as expected, but then my SCRIPT_FILENAME line changes from:

```
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

To:

```
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

And this breaks direct PHP file calls -- something I don't want.

**Edit: Solution**: Answered below: The issue had to do with order of matching. Pattern matching is first found, not last discovered.

Switching their order worked. It failed the first `try_files` because the pattern explicitly looked for starting with `/`.

I was reading: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

> A request “/index.php” is also matched by the prefix location “/”
>   first and then by the regular expression “.(php)$”. Therefore, it is **handled by the latter location** and the request is passed to a FastCGI server listening on localhost:9000.

Comment: Have you tried `index index.php` in your first `location` section?

Comment: Or, just in your `http` section would be better.

Comment: Doesn't work. I do have a global `index` directive. I added one here, and no go-either.

Nginx is picking up the file `/v1.0/index.php` as a static file and displaying it outright (I added `default_type text/plain` globally to prevent download default of application/oct... stream).

Comment: What's the behaviour without any `try_files` directive? I find `index` alone works for me, but I just started working with Nginx a few weeks ago after years of Apache, so it's quite possible I don't know what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that regex locations are evaluated in file order, so if `/v1.1` matches the first location block, then `/v1.1/index.php` will also match the first location block. You seem to fix the problem in the wrong way by creating bad URIs with a missing leading `/`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

You need to place your `location ~ \.php$` block *before* your `location ~ ^/(?<version>v[\d\.]+)` block in order to allow `.php` files with the version prefix to be processed by the PHP block.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. That was it. Thanks! I thought it was an "overloading" pattern (last in rules):

"A request “/index.php” is also matched by the prefix location “/” first and then by the regular expression “\.(php)$”. Therefore, it is handled by the latter location and the request is passed to a FastCGI server listening on localhost:9000" -- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html